# ttk Entry widget font being overwritten by theme

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry, ttk, python-3.10, python-3.11

Does anyone know why the `ttk.Entry` widget font is being overwritten when creating the widget outside of a function called by a Button but it retains the font correctly if you create the widget using a `ttk.Button`?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sv_ttk

def newEntry():
    entry = ttk.Entry(gui, font="Calibri 14 bold")
    entry.pack()

gui = tk.Tk()

sv_ttk.set_theme("dark")

entry = ttk.Entry(gui, font="Calibri 14 bold")
entry.pack()

button = ttk.Button(gui, text="New Entry", command=lambda: newEntry())
button.pack()

gui.mainloop()
```

I have tried using `ttk.Styles()` to add a style to the `ttk.Entry` widget and that does not work either.

Comment: Author of sv-ttk here. With sv-ttk version 2.4.5 your code will work as expected. The theme no longer overwrites explicitly set fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your `gui` after setting the theme to dark:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sv_ttk

def newEntry():
    entry = ttk.Entry(gui, font="Calibri 14 bold")
    entry.pack()

gui = tk.Tk()

sv_ttk.set_theme("dark")
gui.update()

entry = ttk.Entry(gui, font="Calibri 14 bold")
entry.pack()

button = ttk.Button(gui, text="New Entry", command=lambda: newEntry())
button.pack()

gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Huh. I could have sworn I tried that at one point in the last 4 hours of debugging this... Thank you!! :)